# Disable (nxt/prv) buttons if there is no more pics

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I already asked same question here
after that i came up with this code :

css

```
div#big_container{
margin:0;
padding:30px;
width: 230px;
height: 130px;
border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
text-align: center;
z-index:-100;
}

div#container{
overflow: hidden;
width: 207px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

div#content {
position:relative;

}

button#left{
position:absolute;
top:90px;
left:2px;
z-index:1;
}

button#right{
position:absolute;
top:90px;
left:246px;
z-index:1;
}
```

jquery

```
var size =  $("#content table").find('tr').first().find('td').size();
var position = 1;

    $("#left").click( function() {
    if(position < (size / 2)) {
        $('#right').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#content").animate({"right": "+=198px"}, "fast");
         position ++;
    }else{
       $('#left').attr("disabled", "true");
    }
    });


    $("#right").click( function() {
    if( position > 1) {
        $('#left').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#content").animate({"right": "-=198px"}, "fast");
         position --;
    }else{
        $('#right').attr("disabled", "true");
    }
    });
```

html

```
<button id="left"><<</button>
<button id="right">>></button>

<div id="big_container">
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src='http://i53.tinypic.com/1114gbd.gif' border='0' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description1</td>
<td>Description2</td>
<td>Description3</td>
<td>Description4</td>
<td>Description5</td>
<td>Description6</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is ok with me but see on the live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bm4G4/

you see that the nxt and prv buttons disabled but not immediately after the pics set finished! you should click on the button one more time to disable it,

How can i make these buttons disable immediately?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
$("#left").click( function() {
if(position < (size / 2)) {
    $('#right').removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#content").animate({"right": "+=198px"}, "fast");
     position ++;
}if(position >= (size / 2)){
   $('#left').attr("disabled", "true");
}
});


$("#right").click( function() {
if( position > 1) {
    $('#left').removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#content").animate({"right": "-=198px"}, "fast");
     position --;
}if(position == 1){
    $('#right').attr("disabled", "true");
}
});
```

Comment: thank you its work now but i forgot something , how can i make the left button disabled from the begining? thank you for your help

Comment: 101 , Thank you for your concern its much bertter

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bm4G4/1/
and you should really reverse the direction of the animation, the way it's now is confusing.

```
$("#left").click(function() {
    $('#right').removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#content").animate({
        "right": "+=198px"
    }, "fast");
    position++;

    if (position == (size / 2)) {
        $('#left').attr("disabled", "true");
    }
});


$("#right").click(function() {

    $('#left').removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#content").animate({
        "right": "-=198px"
    }, "fast");
    position--;
    if (position == 1) {
        $('#right').attr("disabled", "true");
    }
});
```